# 2017 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2017 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://superuser.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: If there was a way to disable notifications about these elections if one doesn't care at all, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Was the primary just skipped? I admit I'm not terribly active on Super User but wasn't nominations just put up last week?

Comment: I only voted to get a badge.

Comment: @JeffMercado if there are less than 10 candidates, there is no primary.